# How can I reference a column with a space in the name?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run a statement where I retrieve tuples from a database. However my attribute has a space which is "State Name".

Im calling the SQL statement as follows:

```
select * from States where State Name = 'Michigan';
```

I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the attribute having a space. How can I fix this problem without changing the name of the attribute? How can I call a SQL statement with the attribute constraint having a space?

Thanks,

Comment: A better title for the question might be "how to query with attribute name that contains a space"

Comment: This is a SQL question, not an ASP.Net question so I changed the tag and some wording

Comment: SQL Server (and thus T-SQL) is implied, I understand...

Answer (score 10):

```
select * from States where [State Name] = 'Michigan';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try throwing square brackets around it:

```
select * from States where [State Name] = 'Michigan';
```

Answer (score 2):

The Standard SQL delimiter (and supported by SQL Server) is the double quote e.g.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM States 
 WHERE "State Name" = 'Michigan';
```