# Alias For Column with Spaces?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I need a query that includes 3 tables and 2 inner joins. One of the column names in my SELECT statement includes a space (an existing database), so it looks something like:

```
SELECT tblCar.Purchase Price AS Price
```

SQL doesn't like the space of course. I tried brackets `[tblCar.Purchase Price]`, and single and double quotation marks `"tblCar.Purchase Price"`, as well as `tblCar.[Purchase Price]`, but none of them fly.

Any ideas how to handle a column name with a space in this SELECT statement?

Comment: [tblCar].[Purchase Price] works for me in MS SQL.

Comment: Is it SQL Server? Which version?

Comment: I've made the following [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55173/1) and `tblCar.[Purchase Price]` is working fine.

Comment: "tblCar"."Purchase Price", ANSI SQL, i.e. more portable. Should work for MS SQL as well.

Answer (score 2):

Each unit needs to be in a separate square bracket, when you do something like:

```
[tblCar.Purchase Price]
```

It considers this to be complete column name, instead try this [tblCar].[Purchase Price]. Check the following links for more details:

[How do you deal with blank spaces in column names in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920671/how-do-you-deal-with-blank-spaces-in-column-names-in-sql-server)

[sql server:what do brackets mean around column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551284/sql-serverwhat-do-brackets-mean-around-column-name)

[How can I reference a column with a space in the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973222/how-can-i-reference-a-column-with-a-space-in-the-name)

In fact you do not need a square bracket for the table name, its required only for the column name with space, so this will also work:

```
tblCar.[Purchase Price]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, If you are using SQL SERVER you can do this,Wrap the names in square brackets.

It is , however, best to avoid spaces in names if possible

```
SELECT [tblCar].[Purchase Price] AS Price
```

Also if anyone gets this problam in MySql than this can be resolved by properly quoting your column names:

```
SELECT `tblCar.Purchase Price` AS Price
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both table name and column name in the brackets like that [tblCar].[Purchase Price]. Putting the table name in quotes doesn't work in MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 R2, tblCar.[Purchase Price] works fine for me. Which version SQL Version are you using??